# How to convert T to particular object

Tags: c#, generics, types

I want to retrieve BalanceAmount from particular Class. How do i do

```
public class SettlePendingAmount<T> : Form
{
        public T Activity { private get; set; }
        private void Initialize()
        {
            var bal = 0
            if (Activity is Invoice)
            {
                bal = ((Invoice)Activity).BalanceAmount;
            }
            if (Activity is Purchase)
            {
                bal = ((Purchase)Activity).BalanceAmount;
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you already have?

Comment: It's kinda an OO anti-pattern to use `if` when polymorphism if not abstration are the better choices, particularly so when using generics.   Consider having both `Invoice` and `Purchase` derive some a common `interface`, perhaps `ISupportMoney`?

Comment: If you find your self checking for types in a generic method you likely need to rethink the problem, and as stated, potentially use an interface

Comment: It's rather unlikely that this should inherit from `Form`. A form and the data it uses should, ideally, be kept separate. Your object should, perhaps, be able to bind to the form, but it shouldn't be part of the form itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you want to use an interface:

```
public interface IBalance
{
    // I inferred int from your var bal = 0;
    // if that's incorrect, feel free to change it
    int BalanceAmount { get; }
}
```

Now we'll add a generic constraint on `T`:

```
public class SettlePendingAmount<T> : Form
    where T: IBalance
```

We'll also need to add this interface to `Invoice` and `Purchase`:

```
public class Invoice : IBalance
{
    public int BalanceAmount { get; } // or get; set; (whatever you currently have)
}

public class Purchase : IBalance
{
    public int BalanceAmount { get; } // or get; set; (whatever you currently have)
}
```

Then we can freely access BalanceAmount:

```
public class SettlePendingAmount<T> : Form
    where T : IBalance
{
    public T Activity { private get; set; }
    
    private void Initialize()
    {
        var bal = Activity.BalanceAmount;
    }
}
```

The downside here is that your `SettlePendingAmount` class can only be constructed for types that implement this interface. From the brief outline of what you're doing, I suspect this is OK.